# WKWebView does not load http URL in iOS 10 and above, html pages are not rendered

Tags: swift, ios11, wkwebview

I am trying to load a `http URL` in `WKWebView`, the page loads perfectly fine on enabling `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` and `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent` in `info.plist` file. But during navigating the Application, html pages are not loaded completely and my custom spinner doesn't disappear.

I have tried to `NSExceptionDomains` but no luck.

Everything works fine when I tried to load url with `https://myurl`

Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer to my above question

`history.back()` was not working on HTML back button in iOS 11. Adding `history.go(-1)` worked for me.